# ng-repeat not rendering elements from indexeddb

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to populate the elements on html page from indexed db for that i used the controller as shown below

```
myapp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {

   $scope.message = "Hello world";
   $scope.name = "sathya"
   $scope.projects = [];
   var prolist = [];
   var sdb = new SDB();
   sdb.On("project", "read", null, function(Store, data) {
       Store.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
           var cursor = event.target.result;
           if (cursor) {
               prolist.push(cursor.value);
               cursor.continue();
           }
       }
   });
   console.log(prolist);
   $scope.projects = prolist;
});
```

And the HTML code is as shown:

```
   <ul class="list-group" id="project-list">
   <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="project in projects">
        <a href="">{{project.projectname}}</a>
   </li>
   </ul>
```

In chrome console i am getting values of prolist variable:

```
Array[4] 0: ObjectisActivated: falseprojectdescription: "changed"projectid: 1 projectname: "hellothisissathya"__proto__: Object1: ObjectisActivated: trueprojectdescription: "second project"projectid: 2 projectname: "hello"__proto__: Object 2: ObjectisActivated: trueprojectdescription: "second project"projectid: 3 projectname: "hello"__proto__: Object 3: ObjectisActivated: trueprojectdescription: "second project"projectid: 4 projectname: "hello"__proto__: Objectlength: 4__proto__: Array[0]
```

but in html its not rendering the project names from each object.

I need to populate the scope.projects list with this array.

Comment: try `$scope.projects.push(cursor.value);` instead of `prolist.push(cursor.value);` and delete the last line `$scope.projects = prolist`

Comment: Not sure if it's digest cycle issue. Try to trigger `$scope.$apply()` inside `onsuccess`.

Comment: sir thanks $scope.projects and $scope.$apply() really works...Thank you..

Comment: Try to avoid triggering $apply on every item. When you will have alot data this will trigger many digest cycles and as your watchers increase you will end up with an unresponding app.You can trigger apply on every 1000(or more) items you get or something like that.